# How can I see which process does the most writes on a specific partition?

Tags: command-line, monitoring, io

I am using Debian Buster and would like to find out which process does the most writes on a specific partition, just like iotop but limited to a single block device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iotop` cannot do that because it reads processes IO counters (`/proc/PID/io`) which are common for all block devices, including virtual filesystems like `tmpfs`.

What you'll need to do is block I/O tracing:

- https://tunnelix.com/debugging-disk-issues-with-blktrace-blkparse-btrace-and-btt-in-linux-environment/
- https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2017/03/28/linux-block-io-tracing/
- https://www.linux.com/topic/networking/linux-block-io-tracing/

As far as I know there are no ready solutions for that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, looks much more complicated than i expected :(